# Added a library to my existing project it build successfully on simulator but get failed on real device, I am unable to run it on device

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I added a library to my existing Xcode project after that it only build on simulator and fail to build on iPhone giving me error "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:"

Does any one help me on same.

I tried several ways to get rid out of this but unfortunately nothing works. I clear derived data quit Xcode, restart my laptop.

I do one thing while adding my library actually library is old and supports arc enabled no, but my project ARC is enabled So I set a flag value to each file of library like "-fno-objc-arc" in Target --> Build phase --> compile sources that make arc enabled false for that particular file. might issue is due to that but I can not able to fix it.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/shashigupta/Git Projects/ClinMd/Common/PNFModule'
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EASession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libPNFPenLib.a(PenController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EAAccessoryManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libPNFPenLib.a(PenController.o)
  "_EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification", referenced from:
      -[_PenController initWithCoder:] in libPNFPenLib.a(PenController.o)
      -[_PenController init] in libPNFPenLib.a(PenController.o)
      -[_PenController dealloc] in libPNFPenLib.a(PenController.o)
  "_EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification", referenced from:
      -[_PenController initWithCoder:] in libPNFPenLib.a(PenController.o)
      -[_PenController init] in libPNFPenLib.a(PenController.o)
      -[_PenController dealloc] in libPNFPenLib.a(PenController.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

it should build successful on real device but only build on simulator.

Comment: According to the error messages, you're not linking Apple's External Accessory library.  (There's also a problem with a directory that you've specified for linking, but that may not be related to the main problem.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that the simulator & real devices support different architectures and you need to build your 'PFNModule' as per the architecture of the platform on which you are running.

I recommend you read this article to understand the nuances of problem you're facing: http://iosbrain.com/blog/2017/01/07/the-heartbreak-of-the-xcode-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-xxx-linker-message/